# Use conda environment in ansi-term

Tags: python, osx, ansi-term, environment

I would like to be able to use `conda activate` to switch between environments in ansi-term. I am running bash in ansi-term from Emacs 27.1 on MacOS Catalina. Currently, executing `conda activate <ENV_NAME>` from a terminal works as expected. However, from ansi-term, it gives the following output:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

`conda init <SHELL_NAME>` doesn't help for any supported value of `<SHELL_NAME>`: it just tells me that none of the relevant dotfiles need to be updated.

I tried executing `source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` in an ansi-term. This allowed `conda activate <ENV_NAME>` to execute without errors. However, while this does update environment variables like `CONDA_PREFIX` and `CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV`, it does not update others like `CONDA_PYTHON_EXE` or the system path, so executing eg `which python` gives `/usr/bin/python` instead of `~/anaconda3/envs/<ENV_NAME>/bin/python`.

I do have exec-path-from shell installed. I also know that I can change the overall python environment used by emacs using something like pyenv-mode, but I specifically want to be able to switch environments in a terminal emulator (for example for running mpi programs).

Comment: From not such a great memory of trying to get `conda` to work with ZSH on Windows, I remember there being two basic problems: (1) `conda` generates some extra stuff for the shell to be added to its init file, but it doesn't really know where that init should be. Also, it might be that Emacs doesn't load your init file when starting `ansi-term`. Not sure how to fix that, if that's true, but worth checking. Another problem was a bug in `conda` scripts that messed up something about parenthesis. It's worth looking into their scripts and trying to debug what exactly it's doing.